# How to post from facebook app to facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, post

I want to post image data from **facebook app** to **facebook page**.

I tried using **stream.publish**. I was able to post image but it is deprecated. And also I was not able to post **link**.

Curl request to post using stream.publish is as under :-

> curl -F 'access_token=dsdsdsd' \
>                            -F 'message=' \
>                            -F 'uid=23434' \
>                            -F 'attachment={"media": [
>                                                       {
>                                                           "type": "image",
>                                                           "src":
>   "http://url.com/videothumb/465_06122010_p_bizpiyushgargeng_48271_10754.jpg"
>                                                       }],
>                                           "name" : "{Markets likely to scale
>   back: ICICI Sec",
>                                           "description" : "ICICI Securities CIO
>   Piyush Garg says theres a fair chance
>   of scaling back in the market as most
>   of the domestic negative news has
>   already b...",
>                                           "caption" : "News"
>                                   }' \
>                            https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish

While using graph API I am not able to publish from my APP.

Rather it is published through my profile.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

http://php-academy.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-post-from-facebook-app-to.html

Comment: Problem is you have to auth the app and get the manage_page token, from there you have to request the accounts/page's you admin adn find the token for the page you want to publish to.. Then with that token you can post to your page...

Comment: I tried each and every step mentioned in documentation. But ultimately it was posted from my profile only :-( I followed [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: What image data are you trying to publish? Am image to a album or an image to a wall, etc? Let me know what percicly your trying to publish and i will get you some sample code...  Also are you using PHP or ?

Comment: I am using PHP. I am trying to pull contents from a remote location, and post that image on wall of Facebook Page

Comment: This is explained thoroughly on Faceboo pages:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/

Answer (score 0):

I made a example in [this](http://guabonline.net23.net/) page, here you have a example to send post to facebook with javascript including post, links and picture, get your friens with image and user, send friends messages and others...hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

As of now the answers are incorrect because obsolete.

Right now the only way to do that is to submit your application for review having the permissions of manage_pages publish_pages in your application. The platform name is server-to-server. 
It still requires a full review and a screencast where you simply describe HOW you use your api.

Otherwise your posts won't be publicly visible.