# auto post fb apps

Tags: facebook

i develop a fb apps called myApp, how to autopost to "myApp application page" from myApp? is there any API to accomplish this? or another script maybe?...

Comment: PHP? ASP? ASP.NET? Javascript? Can we maybe get a little something to work with here? :)

Comment: [This](http://php-academy.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-post-from-facebook-app-to.html) link will solve your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are asking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217637/how-to-post-from-facebook-app-to-facebook-page).